# How do I resolve the error ORA-06413: Connection not open on VBA

Tags: vba, oracle

My environment：

Windows 10 64 bit

office 2013 32 bit

Oracle 11g Home 32 bit

```
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim myOracleDriver As String
    Dim myOracleServer As String 
    Dim myAccount As String                 
    Dim myPassword As String        
    
    Set myCon = New ADODB.Connection
    Set myRst1 = New ADODB.Recordset
  
    myCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={" & myOracleDriver & "};SERVER=" & myOracleServer & ";UID=" & myAccount & ";PWD=" & myPassword & ""

    SQL = ""
    SQL = SQL + " SELECT CST1,LOT_1,CST2,LOT_2"
    SQL = SQL + " FROM mydb"

    mydata1.Select
    Range("A1").Select
     
    With myCon
        .Open
    End With
```

1. Already check the TNSNAMES.ora, SQLNET.ora, LISTENER.ora and its nothing wrong
2. Try below action and connect both folder success

```
C:>mkLink /j "Program Files x86" "Program Files (x86)"
```

error: connection not open

why error still stuck on myCon.open?

Comment: On which line does the error occur?  Can you `tnsping` the database from your PC?

Comment: error on myCon.open

I try to tnsping my database. It can work from sqlnet.ora

Comment: Have you tried installing the Oracle client to (eg) `C:\Oracle\` instead of its current location?

Comment: Not yet. My original installation site at D:\Oracle. I may try re-install my oracle client.

Comment: Maybe post the rest of your code - you don't show where you try to open the connection (is that when the error occurs?)

Comment: I have post my code on the top

Comment: I re-install my oracle client just now. The Error doesn't appear. Thank you Tim :)

Comment: Good to hear you got it resolved